# Elementary block matrix operations to block-triangularize block tridiagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, block-matrices, tridiagonal-matrices

For some flow modeling purpose, the system $(S)$ defined as $MX=L$ is solved, where $M$ is a tridiagonal block matrix defined as

$$ M= \begin{pmatrix}B_1& C_1 &0 &0  \\ A_2 & B_2 &  C_2 & 0 \\ 0& A_3 & B_3 & C_3 \\ 0 & 0 & A_4 & B_4\end{pmatrix} $$

and $L$ is a block vector defined as

$$ L = \begin{pmatrix} L_1 \\ L_2 \\ L_3 \\ L_4 \end{pmatrix}$$

For some physical constraints, I need to get rid of the block $A_4$ and have the last line as

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & X \end{pmatrix}$$

where $X$ is the resultant block after transforming $M$. Note that $A_i$ blocks are not invertible.

Here are two ideas I thought about using my humble matrices background, but I'm not sure they're right (*I'm assuming the same properties of simple matrices are available for block matrices, which is not always true..*) :

1. Change the third column $Col_3$ as follows : $Col_3 <- Col_3 - A_4B_4^{-1}Col_4 $. The results retrieved were wrong...
2. Multiplying $M$ on the left by the matrix $$ \begin{pmatrix}I& 0 &0 &0  \\ 0 & I &  0 & 0 \\ 0& 0 & I & 0 \\ Z_1 & Z_2 & Z_3 & I\end{pmatrix} $$ and try to find $Z_i$ as a function of the blocks $A_i, B_i$ and $C_i$ so I'd have the last line in a $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & X \end{pmatrix}$ format. The computation was a bit complicated and didn't give good results.

How can I transform M to have its last line in a $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & X \end{pmatrix}$ format and have the same solution as the $(S)$ system ?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't LU decomposition (factorisation) of M help?

Comment: I like the idea. It would certainly help although I'll have to change much more in the code! I'll give it a try once I'm sure the "simple methods" wouldn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that idea (1) is the most promising. Applying your "column operation" yields
$$
\pmatrix{B_1& C_1 &0 &0  \\ A_2 & B_2 &  C_2 & 0 \\ 0& A_3 & B_3 & C_3 \\ 0 & 0 & A_4 & B_4} 
\overbrace{\pmatrix{I & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & I & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & I & 0\\
0 & 0 & -B_4^{-1}A_4 & I}}^P = 
\pmatrix{B_1& C_1 &0 &0  \\ A_2 & B_2 &  C_2 & 0 \\ 0& A_3 & B_3-C_3B_4^{-1}A_4 & C_3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & B_4}.
$$
Now, instead of solving $MX = L$, we could solve $(MP)(P^{-1}X) = L$.  That is, solve $(MP)Y = L$, then noting that $M (PY) = L$, set $X = PY$.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I just guess you mean "Now, instead of solving MX=L" rather than " ...solving  ML=0"

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. You're welcome